# Element visibility tied to radiobutton group selection causes the group to freeze

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I have a data bound RadioButton group in which one RadioButton (Replace) controls the visibility of another element.
When I select the Replace button the group becomes unresponsive. Interestingly, so does the form Cancel button. However, the OK button, which is implemented as a command continues to function (The Cancel button is just implemented as IsCancel="true").

```
<Border x:Name="pnlOptions" Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="25">
                <GroupBox TextElement.FontSize="14" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <RadioButton GroupName="grpOptions" Margin="10,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SegmentSplitOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:eSegmentSplitOption.Replace},Mode=TwoWay}">Replace original segment.</local:RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="grpOptions" Margin="10,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SegmentSplitOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:eSegmentSplitOption.Start},Mode=TwoWay}">Place at Start.</local:RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="grpOptions" Margin="10,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SegmentSplitOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:eSegmentSplitOption.Finish},Mode=TwoWay}">Place at End.</local:RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="grpOptions" Margin="10,10,0,10" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SegmentSplitOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:eSegmentSplitOption.Mid},Mode=TwoWay}">Place at Drop Location.</local:RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </Border>

            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding DurationVisibility}">
                 <Label>Duration</Label>
            <local:TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtDuration" Width="80"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="14"
                     Text="{Binding Path=DurationMinutes, Converter={StaticResource DecimalHoursConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource GeneralTextBoxStyle}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">(hh.dd)</Label>
            </StackPanel>
```

```
       private eSegmentSplitOption _SegmentSplitOption;
        public eSegmentSplitOption SegmentSplitOption
        {
            get { return _SegmentSplitOption; }
            set
            {
                if (_SegmentSplitOption != value)
                {
                    _SegmentSplitOption = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SegmentSplitOption");
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("DurationVisibility");
                }
            }
         }

        public Visibility DurationVisibility
        {
            get { return _SegmentSplitOption == eSegmentSplitOption.Replace || _SegmentSplitOption == eSegmentSplitOption.NotSet ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay elsewhere in the CmdOK_CanExecute function which had the following code:

```
            e.CanExecute = _SegmentSplitOption == eSegmentSplitOption.Replace || _DurationMinutes.HasValue && _DurationMinutes.Value > 0;
            if (wPrevCanExecute != e.CanExecute && e.CanExecute)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    btnOK.Focus();
                }));
            }
```

The intent was to set focus to the OK button when the command became able to execute. Why this should lock the radio buttons and the Cancel button is still a mystery.